# Store Scroll Position on Scroll Direction Change

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm working on a react module that handles showing and hiding a state element based on scroll position. What I have is functional, but I need to be able to capture `scroll position` on direction change.

Here are the relevant code snippets, all bindings and event listeners are functional:

```
this.state = {
  lastScrollPos: 0,
  down: true
};

_scrollFunction() {
  const thisPos = window.pageYOffset;
  const down = thisPos > this.state.lastScrollPos;

  if (down) {
    this.setState({
      down: true,
      lastScrollPos: thisPos
    });
  } else if (!down) {
    this.setState({
      down: false,
      lastScrollPos: thisPos
    });
  }

}
```

In  `_scrollFunction()` above, setting `lastScrollPos: thisPos` gives me the scroll position right before the page scrolled again.

My question is how can I capture the scroll position of when the scroll direction changed. If I'm scrolling down then scroll up, I need to know the place that it occurred and vice versa.

Any advice towards this is appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check in `_scrollFunction` whether current `down` value is differs from `down` value from state. If yes, write `thisPos` value to `changedPos` state variable.

Working example:

```js
constructor() {
  super();

  this.state = {
    lastScrollPos: 0,
    changedPos: undefined,
    down: true
  };
}

_scrollFunction() {
  const thisPos = window.pageYOffset;
  const down = thisPos > this.state.lastScrollPos;
  // If current `down` value is differs from `down` from state,
  // assign `thisPos` to variable, else assigning current `changedPos` state value.
  const changedPos = down !== this.state.down ? thisPos : this.state.changedPos;

  this.setState({
    lastScrollPos: thisPos,
    changedPos,
    down
  });
}
```

Also, I've made working demo on [CodePen](http://codepen.io/1ven/pen/vKVgKv?editors=0011), you can check it out for additional info.

Comment: Beautiful, this is exactly the explanation I needed. Thank you for taking the time to help me with this!